# Linearization of Seiberg-Witten Functional

Tags: gauge-theory

I was reading John Morgan's book "The Seiberg-Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds" and was a little confused by his statement of the linearization of the Seiberg-Witten functional.

As formulated, given a four-manifold $X$ we fix a $\text{Spin}^c$-structure with complex determinant line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ and spinor bundles $S^{\pm}$.

The Seiberg-Witten functional for a $U(1)$ connection $A$ on $\mathcal{L}$ and a section $\psi$ of the positive spinor bundle $S^+$ is then given by
$$F(A, \psi) = (F_A^+ - q(\psi), D_A(\psi)).$$

Here $F_A^+$ denotes the self-dual part of the curvature of $A$, while $q(\psi)$ is an endomorphism of $S^+$ given by $\psi \otimes \psi^* - \frac{1}{2}|\psi|^2\text{Id}$ which with some work can be identified with an imaginary self-dual two-form.

The operator $D_A$ is the Dirac operator of $A$. Then, the claim is that the differential at $(A, \psi)$ is given by 
$$DF_{(A, \psi)} = \begin{pmatrix} P_+d & -Dq_\psi \\ \cdot \frac{1}{2}\psi & D_A \end{pmatrix}.$$

The entries in the right-hand column make sense to me since the top right is tautological and the Dirac operator is linear. Also, the bottom left entry should follow from the fact that $D_{A + \alpha} = D_A + \frac{1}{2}\alpha \cdot \psi$, where $\alpha$ is some imaginary one-form.

However, I'm not sure what "$P_+d$" is, and why it is the linearization of $F_A^+$ with respect to $A$. Any hints or explanations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: P_+ denotes the projection of a 2-form into its self-dual component.

Answer (score 1):

Since the projection $P^{+}$ is already linear, you only remains to linearize the curvature $F^{A}$, 
in fact, $\frac{d}{dt}F^{A+tB}=\frac{d}{dt}(d(A+tB)+(A+tB)\wedge(A+tB))$, a one form wedge itself is zero, thus only $dB$ is left over in the end.

You can refer to my blog [caveman.blog- Linearizaion](https://caveman.blog), for a complete computation in example 2, it also contain a general method of how one can linearize any nonlinear system.